# How to check for files existence from a list ignoring case using bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, filenames

I am working on a script that is looking into an input file and exacting it to make up a filename. Than I want to check for the file existence but ignoring the case.

```
for pattern in `grep -o [[:alnum:]]......-..-.. $inputfile | tr -d - | sed 's/./&./9' | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
do
test -e $pattern || printf "Pattern $pattern is missing.\n"
test -e $pattern && cp $pattern $dirname && printf "Pattern $pattern copied to $dirname\n" done
```

Example of contents in input file:

```
TEST,
$   (AU,PIUSALO-GO-25,AD=.25)
ROWS 5200/14100
TEST 2,
$   (AU,PIUSALO-GO-60,AD=.25)
ROWS 5200/14100
```

So after my grep command I will have 
    `piusalogo.25` and  `piusalogo.60` as my filenames. The actual file might have mixed case in filename. How do I check if file exists ignoring case?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] -- code that can be run by people who aren't you (and don't have your `/some/other/$dirname` on disk), with input and desired output (and self-contained enough that if it needs a file to exist, it *creates that file* first)? I'd also suggest running this through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a definitive answer given the vagueness of your question.

In bash, you can do something like this

```
files=(*)               # array of the files in the current directory
file="Foo.Bar.txt"

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${f,,}" = "${file,,}" ]]; then
        echo "'$file' matches '$f' case insensitively"
    fi
done
```

demo

```
touch FOO.BAR.TXT foo.bar.txt fOo.BaR.tXt
# then run above code
```

outputs

```
'Foo.Bar.txt' matches 'FOO.BAR.TXT' case insensitively
'Foo.Bar.txt' matches 'fOo.BaR.tXt' case insensitively
'Foo.Bar.txt' matches 'foo.bar.txt' case insensitively
```